# 2013 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest

Tags: discussion, election

The following is a "digest" version of the [2013 Moderator Election Town Hall Chat](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/2013-moderator-election-town-hall-chat). The format, [as described on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests), is one *answer* to this question *for every question* asked in the Town Hall, containing all the candidate's answers to that question.

**To view the digest chronologically, please sort the answers by "oldest"**.

If you have questions or comments about this, **please do not answer this question** as the answers are designed to be used for the questions from the Town hall itself. Instead, please ask on [the parent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests) or in [the Town Hall Discussion Room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion).

If you see any corrections which need to be made to this digest, or if you were a candidate who was unable to attend the town hall and would like your answers included, please @GraceNote or @TimStone [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2321/science-fiction-fantasy-town-hall-chat) and let us know!

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: PearsonArtPhoto] [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285379#8285379):* **What specifically do you think that the current moderators are doing well, and what do you think could be improved?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285604#8285604):**  They do an excellent job of steering the community towards debating issues with the site.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285634#8285634):**  The current moderators do a good job of keeping track of current policy, providing expert assistance and guidance, and generally monitoring the flow of questions/answers. I feel like the current team is a solid mix of all the primary elements of moderation.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285662#8285662):**  I think the current moderators are doing well at handling flags in a timely fashion, and keeping the community consensus. I can't identify anything they particularly need improvement on.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285671#8285671):**  Doing well : Keeping the site clean. Could be improved : (not only the moderator but the community as a whole) better guide the new users.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: PearsonArtPhoto] [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285688#8285688):* **Why do you personally want the power and responsibility of being a moderator?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285723#8285723):**  I live for power. Responsibility, what's that? I kid people. It is the next step in the involvement of the site.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285876#8285876):**  Just wish to help. I sincerely care for scifi.stackexchange

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285885#8285885):**  I care a lot about this community.  Its a great resource for me, and it is about a subject that has been a major influence throughout my entire life, on a platform that I have really grown to appreciate throughout my time here.  Mostly, though, because I think I'd be good at it, and because I feel it would increase my ability to help out.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285921#8285921):**  I want the power to take action when needed to keep the site clean and welcoming, and for that I am willing to take the responsibilities of a moderator.

**[image: Nathan C. Tresch] [Nathan C. Tresch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36834/nathan-c-tresch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285924#8285924):**  Because I think that this is an amazing forum for genre enthusiasts to discuss what they're passionate about and I want to do whatever I can to help.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Keen] [Keen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9586/keen) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285756#8285756):* **What would you do to encourage more community self-moderation?  That is, high-rep users making use of their moderation powers to close, edit, reopen, and delete posts.**

---

**[image: Nathan C. Tresch] [Nathan C. Tresch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36834/nathan-c-tresch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285897#8285897):**  I'm not sure what could be done to encourage the community to self-moderate beyond giving positive attention and feedback to people who do.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285929#8285929):**  I'm generally pretty impressed with how many people respond with close/reopen/edits.  However, I would continue to do what I have done in the past on this site: point out through comments and meta discussion when I think action needs to be taken.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285991#8285991):**  As a frequent user in chat, where most of our high-rep users hang out, I would remind people there to use what privileges they have accrued.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286085#8286085):**  It's hard to directly communicate with users that don't come to chat. I think the best way is to make the community feels responsible for the site, they need to care for it. Soliciting the opinion of user and showing you respect them is a good way.

Answer (score 2):

### *[Gilles http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a717291747c76567bb0f086e15ae6e43?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a717291747c76567bb0f086e15ae6e43?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Gilles](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/240/gilles) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286047#8286047):* **A genie grants you a wish: you may change one site policy (e.g. make a type of question on/off topic, change some tagging habits, …) (SE policies remain). What is your wish?**

---

**[Jack B Nimble http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286054#8286054):**  To ban the why didn't X recognize Y in the original work when they had encountered each other in a prequel.

**[Beofett http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286122#8286122):**  Honestly, I can't think of anything I'd want to change by fiat.  Recommendations are always fun, but they are such a poor fit for the platform I wouldn't want them on-topic.  I can spot inconsistencies in tag usage, but I'm not invested in them enough to feel comfortable declaring a blanket change. I do think the [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) situation and related issues is a mess, though, so perhaps a complete rework of how they should be used.

**[Kevin http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3bec657e9d57297e9f090b7aed2cda00?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3bec657e9d57297e9f090b7aed2cda00?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286206#8286206):**  Ban questions on minor secondary plot-holes that almost certainly have no answer.

**[DavRob60 http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0964ccfd92e2c634db90489311f22fa6?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0964ccfd92e2c634db90489311f22fa6?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286263#8286263):**  This is an hard one. I don't disagree to *any* site policies that much.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285340#8285340):* **In your opinion, what do moderators do?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285371#8285371):**  They help to maintain the rules and community consensus on what is appropriate for the site. They make mitigating decisions on flags and other criteria that the community thinks requires attention.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285431#8285431):**  Moderators keep order in the community, ensuring a pleasant experience for all. They gently enforce the community consensus.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285439#8285439):**  They are the "human exception handler", mostly dealing with the flag queue. Also keep the site clean from clearly unwanted stuff.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285443#8285443):**  Primarily moderators help facilitate. They facilitate discussion on policy, scope, etc. They also serve as the peace-keepers for disputes/flags.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: PearsonArtPhoto] [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285353#8285353):* **What SFF books have you read in the last month? Please list as many as you can**

---

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285500#8285500):**  Unfortunately, I haven't really been reading much, I don't think I've read any full book in the last month.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285534#8285534):**  *Hyperion*, *Fall of Hyperion* (currently reading), *The Order of the Stick: Snips, and Snails, and Dragons Tails*, *Vor Games*, and I can't remember what I read before *Vor Games*....

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285584#8285584):**  Currently reading *The Lost Symbol, from Dan Brown*, read *Scott  Orson Card's Shadow* of the Giant and *Iain M. Banks's Excession* lately

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285519#8285519):* **What are your three favorite scifi/fantasy works, and your three least favorite?**

---

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285669#8285669):**  Hard question... I'm going to have to say my favorites are: *A Fire Upon the Deep*, *Dune*, and *Stranger in a Strange Land*.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285718#8285718):**  My least favorite: *The Saga of Seven Suns*, the *Dune* prequels, and *Twilight* (although I have to admit I haven't read/watched it)

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285698#8285698):**  Top are the LotR trilogy, Silmarillion, and Ender's game.  As for the bottom, I can't recall any SFF I particularly disliked.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285717#8285717):**  *Favorite* : The *Tron* universe as a whole, probably the reason why I'm a programmer right now.  *Least favorite* : I don't like horror in general.

**[image: Nathan C. Tresch] [Nathan C. Tresch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36834/nathan-c-tresch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286020#8286020):**  The Solar Cycle by Gene Wolfe, the Robots series by Asimov and anything by Phillip K. Dick.  My least favorite is any space opera from the early 20th century.

Answer (score 1):

### *[PearsonArtPhoto http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fdc52692a8ac266cd1c897f75a0f75f8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fdc52692a8ac266cd1c897f75a0f75f8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285658#8285658):* **Which tag do you wish to see grown the most on this site?**

---

**[Jack B Nimble http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285750#8285750):**  I would love to see more fantasy questions at large. Harry Potter may be the top tag on the site, but you have to go a long ways down to find a second place (LOTR).

**[Beofett http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285840#8285840):**  There's not one particular tag I'd like to see grown.  However, I think there are a ton of great titles out there that have very few questions.  I'd like to grow those tags: the ones that are on works widely regarded as "classics", yet which have received little attention on our site so far.

**[DavRob60 http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0964ccfd92e2c634db90489311f22fa6?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0964ccfd92e2c634db90489311f22fa6?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285858#8285858):**  I always enjoy [tron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tron) questions. But there is also classic Sci-fi author that could be more present ([arthur-c-clarke](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthur-c-clarke), [frank-herbert](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frank-herbert), etc)

**[Kevin http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3bec657e9d57297e9f090b7aed2cda00?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3bec657e9d57297e9f090b7aed2cda00?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285894#8285894):**  I don't have a particular preferred tag, I want to see whatever tag grow that will bring in new users that stay around and become productive members of our site.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: PearsonArtPhoto] [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285754#8285754):* **What SFF TV series/ Movies have you watched in the last month?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285780#8285780):**  DS9, Phineas & Ferb, Escape from Planet Earth, and some others.

**[image: Nathan C. Tresch] [Nathan C. Tresch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36834/nathan-c-tresch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285783#8285783):**  The Walking Dead

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285900#8285900):**  I don't get to watch nearly as much TV as I used to, but I believe I've watched *Walking Dead* and *Misfits* in the past month.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285962#8285962):**  Star Trek: The Next Generation and Star Trek: Insurrection.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286001#8286001):**  Many thing: The Masters of Time, The *Total recall* 2012 remake, the *Mtal Hurlant Chronicles* series, My little pony friendship is magic (with my daughter). And I probably forget some...

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Keen] [Keen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9586/keen) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285913#8285913):* **How do you encourage more participation in meta?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285976#8285976):**  When a question is generating lots of debates in comments it is usually recommended to move the discussion to meta.

**[image: Nathan C. Tresch] [Nathan C. Tresch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36834/nathan-c-tresch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285980#8285980):**  For starters I think that just advertising it exists would help.  I was on here for a long time before I knew what it was.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286044#8286044):**  The best way to promote participation in meta... is to participate in meta.  Start discussions based upon issues that come up in comments/chat, then link the meta discussion and ask people to chime in.  The biggest problem with meta is that people forget/don't know it is there.  Frequent reminders are the best remedy to that.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286150#8286150):**  As I mentioned, I'm quite active in chat, along with most of our high rep users, so I discuss things there with them, and point them at the appropriate meta posts.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286204#8286204):**  Inviting users to ask question on Meta though comments when needed. Directing them there when there is information they need to know and be kind and respectful when they come to meta to keep them there.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Keen] [Keen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9586/keen) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286109#8286109):* **How would you deal with a user who posts lots of quality content, but also generates a large number of flags?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286143#8286143):**  Try to communicate the issues that come up in their posts with the user. I know we've had a few users who meet this criteria and I've seen the moderators try to work with them. I think that has positively influenced the quality of these users posts.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286160#8286160):**  This is never a fun situation.  The first thing I'd do is just talk with them.  Make it clear that their contributions are valued, but no one contributes enough to exempt them from the rules, particularly the "be nice" rule.  If needs be, I would have no qualms about suspending a user, regardless of the quality of their contributions, if their behavior is problematic.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286229#8286229):**  Warn them in comments, then chat if they are a chat user and don't respond, then send them a mod-message if they still don't shape up. Posting good content does not offset bad behavior.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286315#8286315):**  It depend if the flags are founded and the kind of flag. A user who is Offensive must be disciplined. Otherwise, I would comment on his questions and try to explain him how he could improve himself.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: DVK] [DVK](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9454/dvk) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286236#8286236):* Related to that, DVK also asks: **What is your threshold for binding-voting to close a question? "I would have VTCed it if my vote wasn't binding"? A critical mass of unopposed VTCs and flags? Do you consider NOT voting (and opening a meta discussion) if the comments on the question indicate a clear LACK of consensus on closing and it wasn't discussed on meta yet?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286275#8286275):**  I always consider not taking action as a valid course. I don't like rash decisions.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286302#8286302):**  Again, it depends. A flag of "I find this offensive" gets a lot more weight than a flag of "this question is silly".

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286305#8286305):**  A question that has been open for a couple of hours and has no close votes from the community would get more consideration from me than one that has been open 15 minutes and already has 4 close votes.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [concluded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286312#8286312):**  I would definitely consider a meta discussion, but wouldn't *necessarily* hold off on voting, as the question could always be reopened after the meta discussion (for example, the question could be worded poorly, but a meta discussion might involve some suggested edits that would improve the question enough to reopen it).

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286351#8286351):**  No threshold if I don't have any doubt (but I assure you that I'm a doubtful person). Waiting to be the 5th vote otherwise.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286417#8286417):**  If a question clearly needs closing, I will use my binding vote. If it is more contested, I will normally wait and see if close votes pile up, and usually only close as the 4th or 5th vote (and, as came up in the previous question, check the close queue results for it).

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: PearsonArtPhoto] [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286328#8286328):* **A high reputation user was accused of harassing a lower ranking user. What do you do?**

---

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286359#8286359):**  Reputation is a "rough measurement of how much the community trusts you", not a licence to behave inappropriately. I would verify the if the accusations are founded and take the appropriate action if necessary, depending of the degree of the harassment.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286376#8286376):**  I **do not** give the higher reputation user more leeway than the lower ranking user; if anything, it works the opposite.  I expect the higher reputation users to know better than a new user (generally anyone who has 500 rep or less).

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286381#8286381):**  The first thing I do is review any specific instances pointed out.  Then I look at the activity log for both users, checking comments.  I look at any post where there appears to be comments between the two users in question.  I then use a couple of tools available to moderators to make sure I have as complete a picture of the activity between the two users as possible.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [concluded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286383#8286383):**  If I see evidence of policy violations, I'll bring it up to the other moderators and discuss it as a team.  If I see evidence of severe violations (threats, abusive language, irregular voting patterns, etc.) I'll probably also bring it to the attention of the SE community team.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286542#8286542):**  Assure the complainant that moderators do, in fact, care just as much about low-rep users and won't just give high-reps a free pass (in fact, I hold them to a higher standard), then investigate the accusation.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: PearsonArtPhoto] [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285343#8285343):* **If you had one minute to explain this site to someone, what would you say that it is?**

---

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285476#8285476):**  A place where you could ask and answer questions about science fiction and fantasy.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285482#8285482):**  This is a site where one can ask a concrete, finitely answerable (not open-ended, not a list) question and get a great response from a group of enthusiasts.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285485#8285485):**  Primarily this is a great place to answer any question on sci-fi or fantasy works that nag at you after watching/reading, and an even better place to find out about aspects of the material you never knew about, or even entire new works to check out.

Answer (score 0):

### *[Keen http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/17c0190cc521c554c0d4555edbe76f4c?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/17c0190cc521c554c0d4555edbe76f4c?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Keen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9586/keen) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285587#8285587):* **What is your position on [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions?  Should they be allowed or banned?**

---

**[Jack B Nimble http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285636#8285636):**  I've noticed that many of the unanswered questions are story-identification questions. It was decided early on that these questions would be allowed. It is my opinion that there is a real quality issue with these questions, but until the community changes their mind on these questions, they should continue to be allowed.

**[Kevin http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3bec657e9d57297e9f090b7aed2cda00?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3bec657e9d57297e9f090b7aed2cda00?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285744#8285744):**  Story identification questions are fine. They have a concrete solution, as long as the OP keeps giving feedback on answers. My main complaint about them is how they are voted on. I think the questions should only be upvoted if they seem to contain enough to identify a story, and answers only if the asker comes back and affirms a guess correct.

**[Beofett http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285752#8285752):**  I continue to be a large fan of [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification).  The questions do an excellent job as a way to bring in new users, which is important for us to continue to function as a community.  While the core regular users are important, a constant influx of new participants is essential.  Plus I get a lot of great ideas for new content to read/watch as a result.

**[DavRob60 http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0964ccfd92e2c634db90489311f22fa6?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0964ccfd92e2c634db90489311f22fa6?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285757#8285757):**  Allowed for now, but I'm a mostly indifferent to those question.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: PearsonArtPhoto] [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285589#8285589):* **As a moderator, you will have to moderate on topics that you haven't read/watched. How will you accomplish that?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285665#8285665):**  Magic, and possibly divination. And whatever the internet can spit out to gain a cursory knowledge in a short time frame.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285770#8285770):**  Getting to chat when exteriors expertise is needed.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285802#8285802):**  Moderating topics you aren't familiar with isn't usually that hard.  The community response (VTCs, flags, comments, etc.) is usually a good indication of whether or not there is a problem.  Wikipedia can be of surprising help, but the biggest resource is asking opinions in chat, either of the regular members, or other moderators (or both).

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285870#8285870):**  Most of a moderator's work is topic-agnostic. In most cases, one doesn't need to know the particulars of a work to see most problems with a post, and the community members who are familiar with it will point out when action actually does need to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: PearsonArtPhoto] [PearsonArtPhoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285786#8285786):* **What have you personally done already to help moderate this site?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285826#8285826):**  Flagged, VTC, reviews, editting, and reading through a lot of the questions.

**[image: Nathan C. Tresch] [Nathan C. Tresch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36834/nathan-c-tresch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285961#8285961):**  I personally edit my answers to make certain that they are concise and answer the question at hand, and as well I delete my questions and answers that are deemed unworthy by the community.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285974#8285974):**  Aside from voting/closing/flagging/editing, I've been very active in meta.  I have started quite a few discussions on policy here, including the discussions that resulted in community consensus that General Reference was not a good fit as a close reason for our site.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286032#8286032):**  As my badges indicate, I have been very active editing posts and I went through the review queues before they were popular, and I flag posts when warranted; I also vote to close and re-open, and I keep an eye on the 10k flag queue much of the time. In essence, all a 10k can do.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286125#8286125):**  All sort of thing. Voting to Close/reopen question that deserve it. Flagging really inappropriate stuff and discussing in meta /chat when I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: a Slytherin] [a Slytherin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/29121/a-slytherin) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285806#8285806):* **How would you approach supporting and encouraging growth in the fantasy genre on SFF.se if it's not your cup of tea or you are hardcare sci-fi?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285843#8285843):**  I would love to see more fantasy questions on the site.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286013#8286013):**  I find that difficult to speculate on, since I tend to mix both genres pretty evenly.  However, I think the best way to encourage content on particular topics (barring the return of "Topic of the Week" contests) would be to post bounties.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286136#8286136):**  The same as I would for scifi. It's not for the moderators to decide to drop support for half the site's topicality.  That said, I do like fantasy just as much as scifi.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286161#8286161):**  I have more interest into Sci-fi than Fantasy, but I have read both TLOTR and Harry Potter. However, I think Fantasy have his place here and should be encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: DVK] [DVK](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9454/dvk) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286140#8286140):* **What is the threshold at which you consider something as a community imposed general (non-question-specific) policy based on Meta Q&A? E.g. if there is a consensus answer with +3 vote margin, do you consider it a policy? +8 vote margin? No specific threshold aside from your own opinion?**

---

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286171#8286171):**  I don't have a specific threshold, as it varies depending on the circumstances.  Generally, though, for non-question-specific issues, I think time is a bigger factor than vote margin, although vote margin is definitely still a component.  I think discussions should be up long enough to allow sufficient visibility.  For a major policy change, a full week would be the minimum.  If the voting is close, I'd give it more time

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286184#8286184):**  When I determine if I feel voting is close, I factor in the number of down-votes. E.g. after a week, I might consider an answer with 5 upvotes and no downvotes as indicative of consensus, but an answer with 10 upvotes and 5 downvotes I'd leave for another couple of days, at least, since it is clear that a significant portion of the population disagrees.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286226#8286226):**  Generally, though, once sufficient time is allowed, I think a 10+ margin is pretty clear, even if there are a fair number of dissenting votes.  If there are only one or two dissenting votes, I think a margin of 5+ is fair, though.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [concluded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286232#8286232):**  A similar process could be used if there are multiple highly-voted answers that differ significantly.  I'd allow more time for votes, and look for a significant (10+) margin between them.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286289#8286289):**  If an answer has been around a while and there is no upvoted contradictory answer, I would consider that policy. For more contested issues, there is no absolute rule, it's more of a case-by-case basis.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286320#8286320):** The threshold is more a matter of percentage than points. I would consider the total number of vote on the answers vs the others options.  I think we should discuss it in meta before casting those threshold in stone, be here is a rough draft:  50%-66%  Majority : more a guideline than a policy  66%-75%  Strong majority : A candidate to become a policy  75%-100% near Consensus : de facto policy

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: DVK] [DVK](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9454/dvk) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286211#8286211):* **Do you take into account the "Leave open" information from Review queue when applying moderator-binding-close-votes (as opposed to only existing close votes and flags) to obtain a more balanced picture? If such information isn't available, WOULD you have taken it into account if it was?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286253#8286253):**  If I see a review which I can't make a determination I choose to skip it and leave it to someone else better qualified.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286255#8286255):**  The only way I would take it into account is if it provided an explanation as to *why* the reviewer felt it should remain open.  Given that I'd only use a binding close vote if I was very clear that the question needed to be closed (flags, clear dup, spam, blatant NARQ, etc.), "leave open" votes wouldn't be nearly as likely to sway me as comments or a good meta discussion.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286340#8286340):**  As a moderator, I would use my close/reopen vote only on clear case and prefer the skip button whenever there is a doubt.

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286388#8286388):**  If the review queue information were right there on the page, I would definitely take it into account. It is (recently, I believe) available but several clicks and a different screen away for moderators, so I would only check if the question's status seemed contested, from the comments on it.

Answer (score 0):

### *[DVK http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f3d2c01f6f55bb34530fcbae9a39d285?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f3d2c01f6f55bb34530fcbae9a39d285?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [DVK](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9454/dvk) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286282#8286282):* **Please provide an example (specific question) of a moderator action that you would have liked to have taken based on your own opinion but would refrain from taking based on meta or comments achieved community consensus.**

---

**[Jack B Nimble http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286333#8286333):** [Why doesn't Darth Vader recognize C-3PO?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31832/why-doesnt-darth-vader-recognize-c-3po)

**[Jack B Nimble http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/646f9bc3ae8effa7fa1a1a1c528ff522?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286344#8286344):**  As expressed in some of the comments, I am not impressed with these questions.

**[DavRob60 http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0964ccfd92e2c634db90489311f22fa6?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0964ccfd92e2c634db90489311f22fa6?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286355#8286355):** I don't remember any case where I strongly disagree with a community consensus to the point I would have liked to take any action against it.  I prefer having clears rules than blurry frontiers, otherwise we got Velociraptors testing the electric fences every now and then.

**[Beofett http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286364#8286364):**  [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31975/jews-in-star-trek#comment60683_31975).  As a regular user, I cast a delete vote, since there are 4 reopen votes and I don't think it has any justification for being reopened (not one person voting to reopen has accepted my invitation to explain, either in comments or the [meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/how-could-i-have-asked-the-jews-in-star-trek-question-better).

**[Beofett http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4fd4c34547537e3016edb24f106e223?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286368#8286368):**  There's not even a single downvote on either meta answers explaining why the question should be closed).  If I were a moderator, I would not have cast a binding delete vote, and instead waited to see how the issue developed.

Comment: @Jack - "you're dead to me" (c) Jack

Answer (score -1):

### *[image: Gilles] [Gilles](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/240/gilles) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285370#8285370):* **What was the last SFF book you read, and when was it?**

---

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285397#8285397):**  Earth Unaware - Orson Scott Card.

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285548#8285548):**  *Fall of Hyperion* by Dan Simmons (reading currently)

**[image: Kevin] [Kevin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27598/kevin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285549#8285549):**  I think the last SFF book I read must have been Harry Potter and The Chamber of Secrets, this past fall.

**[image: DavRob60] [DavRob60](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20784/davrob60) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8285609#8285609):**  Currently reading The Lost Symbol, from Dan Brown, read Scott Orson Card's Shadow of the Giant and Iain M. Banks's Excession lately

Answer (score -2):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286362#8286362):* **Final thoughts from the candidates**?

---

**[image: Nathan C. Tresch] [Nathan C. Tresch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36834/nathan-c-tresch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286058#8286058):** Everyone, I did my best to be here for this and I hope that what little I was able to answer helps you form an opinion about my qualifications as a moderator.  I have to excuse myself now, my 1 year old daughter's bedtime is 7:30.  I hope I've left the impression that I would be a level headed and a good moderator and that I want the position because I want to help, and that I'd be a great help also.  Thanks for your consideration.

**[image: Nathan C. Tresch] [Nathan C. Tresch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36834/nathan-c-tresch) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8301962#8301962):** One thing I wanted to mention is that I got my most recent job from the Stack Exchange Careers 2.0 site, and that's a huge reason that I'm so passionate about StackEx sites.

**[image: Jack B Nimble] [Jack B Nimble](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3490/jack-b-nimble) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286391#8286391):**  We must move forwards, not backwards, upwards, and not forwards, and always be twirling, twirling, twirling!

**[image: Beofett] [Beofett](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13641/beofett) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8286418#8286418):**  I just want to thank everyone for your time and questions.  I feel quite confident that regardless of the outcome of this election, the site will get 2 great moderators, since we have so many fantastic candidates who have already shown a lot of dedication to this site.