# Why is my question about the limits to the Magic School Bus' magic "too broad"?

Tags: discussion

This question was closed as being too broad: [Are there any limits to the Magic School Bus's magic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174329/are-there-any-limits-to-the-magic-school-buss-magic)

Why is this too broad? It's not something which is reasonably demonstrable. In fact, barring breakdowns, and my own answer, I'm aware of virtually nothing that the Magic School Bus cannot do (which is why I asked this question). How is a question which has nearly no answers that I'm aware of, too broad?

Comment: Is it a list that you're looking for in that question or merely a "yay" or "nay"?

Comment: @Edlothiad a yay or nay

Comment: In that case it should be re-opened and I apologise for misreading your question and making the wrong judgement call re:multiple correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## There are multiple answers that are all equally correct

<sub>This first part is based on the [original title](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/174329/1) of your question.</sub>

Notice [your answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174350/68872) on the question itself. It states that the Magic School Bus "*can't make its own fuel.*", giving evidence and even an image. A great answer, truly, however no *more* accurate than any of the other limits to the Magic School Bus's magic.

There is nothing that makes it such that your answer is *better* at solving the problem than another answer stating one of the Magic School Bus's magical limits. This makes the question too broad, and even though hypothetically an answer can (possibly) be given to list *every* single limit, in it's current state it is allowing too many equally right answers.

Note from the old close vote prompt for Too Broad:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

(Which, in my opinion, is far clearer than the new one)

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

---

Your question however should be re-opened. An often forgotten policy (and one I only remembered thanks to this question) on [How should we handle "any" list questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1490/68872) states that since the answer to your question is simply "Yes", and an actual example is merely additional details it is perfectly on-topic. Some possible things you could do to make it clearer that it is on-topic, is to change the title. Some examples include, but are not limited to:

- Have we ever seen any limitation...
- What canonical limitations have we seen...

<sub>Further Reading:</sub>

<sub>- [Can we get a more specific definition of what this site considers “too broad”?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9782/can-we-get-a-more-specific-definition-of-what-this-site-considers-too-broad)</sub>
 <sub>- [Are we consistent when flagging questions as 'too broad'?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/are-we-consistent-when-flagging-questions-as-too-broad)</sub>
 <sub>- [Is a list question within the scope of Sci-Fi SE if it is a relatively small pool of answers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/is-a-list-question-within-the-scope-of-sci-fi-se-if-it-is-a-relatively-small-poo)</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit question throughly next time I have time.

Comment: So actually a less-broad wording of the same question would be something like "Has there ever been an example of the Magic School Bus being unable to do something?"

Comment: @Omegacron exactly, since that is _technically_ a yes or no question.