# Does the size of the list of works matter?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

The close reason for lists of work or recommendations reads as follows:

> Requests for lists of works or recommendations are off-topic as they do not fit our questions and answers format. Feel free to ask about people's favorites in chat.

It is my understanding that this close reason arose because it tends to allow answers that can all have equal value.

Recently, [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/203679/57310) was asked, closed, and reopened. (Full disclosure: I was the one who cast the initial close vote.)

To me this falls under the list/recommended close reason, but a comment was made the because there are only a limited number of works in the series that it should not be considered as such. A good answer probably could list all the works, but that can be said about any list question given enough time and research. The only thing that might change the circumstance is that the request is for a single defined universe. However, answers that are incomplete or give single works that match the criteria would still be equally valid.

So does the size of list matter when determining whether to close these questions?

Comment: You might also want to note that because this is an *ongoing* series, the list could easily change, resulting in more than one "correct" answer.

Comment: @Valorum We ask questions about ongoing series all the time, and answers get updated as new information comes out. To me that really isn't a problem. The question already has a problem with "more than one correct answer" from the start.

Comment: Sure, but with lists we'll end up with a race to post the latest one, then another race to post the (next) latest one. Each time the answer will be right

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2638/31936)? The linked question is asking for a bounded list, so according to the linked meta the linked question is on topic.

Comment: Note [the answer to "Are *all* list questions off-topic?"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/are-all-list-questions-off-topic/2639#2639), which states that lists like "What works actually include space ships shaped like flying saucers?". It specifically mentions a question asking who are all the Doctors from *Doctor Who*, which at that point was a 13 item list, and is now a 14 item list.

Comment: @RDFozz My argument would be that the DW question is not a list of of works or recommendations which is why they pass.

Comment: @Skooba: You're welcome to make that argument, but it does not appear in the upvoted answer to which RDFozz has linked.  So it's not policy (yet).  Go write an answer to the other meta, if you want to change things.

Comment: They say "size doesn't matter"...